# Validate an inline foreign key field

Tags: django, inline

I'm having problems trying to validate a form so that it only ever picks a distinct partner.  The classes work like this:

```
class EmpployeeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    #.......

class EmployeeRoles(models.Model):
      partner = model.ForeignKey(Partner, relative_name='employee')
      employee = model.ForeignKey(Employee, relative_name='partner')

class EmployeeRolesInline(admin.TabularInline):
      model = EmployeeRoles
      extra = 0
      form = EmployeeRolesForm
```

Inside my forms.py I use the clean_partner function to try and validate that the current Employee only has one partner of the same name.  They can have multiple EmployeeRoles objects with different partners, but they should only be assigned a partner once.

```
class EmployeeRolesForm(forms.ModelForm):
      def clean_partner(self):
          partner = self.cleaned_data.get('partner')
          partner_ids=[int(p.partner_id) for p in self.instance.employee.partners.all()]
          if self.instance.partner_id is not None:
             return
          else:
             if partner.id in partner_ids:
                raise forms.ValidationError("Partner already chosen")
```

This doesn't work, it gives me an error that self.instance.employee.partners.all() is empty.  I think it has something to do with the form being unbounded and I'm not sure how to solve the problem.  It's the same problem I had when I tried to filter the partner selection after every save so you only see the partners you don't have when you try to add a new employeerole.  If anyone can suggest a way around the error I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use [`unique_together`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/options/#unique-together) in your model:

```
class EmployeeRoles(models.Model):
      partner = model.ForeignKey(Partner, relative_name='employee')
      employee = model.ForeignKey(Employee, relative_name='partner')

      class Meta:
          unique_together = (("partner", "employee"),)
```